# What is the meaning of this sentence from the book The magic of Thinking Big?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Few people I know of any age are reaping more from life than this senior citizen who resolved not to got out to **pasture**.

Also what does **pasture** mean here.

Thank You.

Comment: The metaphor "out to pasture" refers to a racehorse being retired.

Comment: @Hot Licks Ok. Thnx :)

Comment: @HotLicks and what does the whole sentence mean?

Comment: @NavneetSrivastava Please ask that and any other follow-up questions you have on our buster site dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language: [ELL.se].

Comment: When someone is "put  out to pasture", he is considered too old to be efficient and asked to retire partially or totally from work.

Comment: @DanBron ok dear.

Comment: Basically it means: One man (he knows) is getting more out of life at a time when he was supposed to be "resting/retired" than almost anyone else of any age that he knows.